# Simple Select, returns 1400 rows, takes 360ms?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that returns me 1400 rows.

It's basic.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.entity_event ee
```

That is taking between 250 and 380ms, averaging though, on the 360ms. I'd expect this to be much quicker. I am running it on a laptop though, but an i7, 8gb, SSD. Does that seem normal, or should it be quicker? The table only has the total result set. No Where clause.

Running:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.entity_event ee WHERE entity_event_type_id = 1
```

Takes the same time.

There is a clustered index on the primary key (id) in the table.

The table has around 15 columns. Mainly dates, ints and decimal(16,2).

If it seems slow, what can I look at to improve this? I do expect the table to become rather large as the system gets used.

I'm unable to track this on my live site, as the host doesn't allow SQL Profile to connect (Permissions). I can only check on my dev machine. It doesn't seem quick when live though.

The issue originates from a VIEW that I have, which is taking 643ms average. It has 8 joined tables, 4 of which are OUTER joins, ruling out the option of an indexed view.

The view, however, does use the column names, including other logic (CASE... ISNULL etc).

EDIT: I notice that SELECT TOP 10 ... Takes 1ms. SELECT TOP 500 .. Takes 161ms... So, it does seem liniar, and related to the volume of data. I'm wondering if this can be improved?

Execution plan:

[image]

Comment: Specifying the fields that you want returned from the query instead of `Select *` may help a little too.

Comment: @JakeGould It appears he is using MSSQL and not MySQL

Comment: It is a fallacy to believe that the clustered index should always be on id, the clustered index should be established for maximum advantage and that could be something other than id.

Comment: Is there anything between your query and the server or, if you prefer, are you running this directly on the server?

Comment: Did you run `EXPLAIN` on the query? It would help to see what the planner is doing. Also there is a "[query analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216928(v=sql.80).aspx)" in case you have access to the SQLServer application

Comment: Execution plan added.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the actual question is? Is it to get that single `select * from entity_event` to go faster? Because without a WHERE that'll never happen without changing hardware/deleting data.

Comment: That is really the crux of it. Why is it taking so long for the simplest of queries, and can it be improved?

Comment: Is this sending rows over a network? How are the rows being processed? In SSMS grid view? Something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks normal to me as it appears it's doing a full scan regardless of the WHERE clause--because the entity_event_type_id is not your PK nor indexed.  So putting that WHERE clause will not help since it's not indexed.

Doing the Top N will help because it knows it doesn't need to scan the whole clustered pk index.

So...Yes it can be improved--if you index entity_event_type_id you would expect a faster time with that WHERE clause.  But as always...index it only if you really will be using that field in WHERE clauses often.
--Jim